# Android - React Native Integration - TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: android, react-native

I'm currently referring to the following guide: https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps and I am able to get my integration working using a local server with Yarn Start.

However when I follow the final step to create a release build, I run the command supplied and modify it to ensure that it is aligned with my project settings.

Original command:

```
$ npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/res/
```

Modified Command:

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

When I create a signed apk with a release variant and install it onto my phone. I launch the app and I see the errors in my logcat from React Native saying:

TypeError: Network request failed

Can someone please provide some info as to why this is occuring?
The react native module loads fine, it's just the network requests it makes are getting that above error.

Some more info of sections of code I used in the files:

build.gradle:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    bundleInDebug: true,
    bundleInRelease: true,
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
 ]
```

AndroidManifest

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Delete all debug folders from your android folder.. if it does not work check your URL are they  SSL enables.  You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25244)

Comment: what does your local host endpoint look like? you may have to try `http://10.0.2.2:[port]` instead of `localhost`

Comment: I'm building for release though? It works locally. Even after successfully building my app for release after following these intrsuctions here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android I am still getting the Network Request Failed hmmm @kenmistry

Comment: _I'm building for release though?_ will the server endpoint be different? what did you mention this and not an answer to your endpoint? also, am i right to interpret your problem, in which you are using your release build from your physical mobile device, an android, to connect to your `local server with yarn start` and facing the network issue?

Comment: Hmmm. I’m sorry if this is a stupid question but Im actually not sure. Earlier you mentioned what my local host endpoint was, I'm not sure what it is or how to check it. Is this a setting inside the react app? But yes you are almost right. I thought that if I build a release then I wouldn't need the local server anymore? I was trying to use it on my physical android phone without having to be connected to my laptop on USB and relying on the yarn start@kenmistry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem: When I activate debug mode, the react native debugger somehow manages to bridge the VPN from my MAcBook and thats why my requests worked. I had forgotten that these requests required a VPN.

What tripped me up was that when I built releaase, the debug was disabled which meant that there would no longer be a bridge between my emulator and the VPN on my laptop.

I don't know why this is the case and it seems to be a very common issue where android emulators do not connect to the VPN on the laptop.

So it was a combination of two issues, one being that I had to be on a VPN and second I was assuming that my emulator was connected to the VPN by default.